# hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args, FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: ssh, subprocess, python-3.8

I am trying to do simple ssh connect with subprocess but getting following error for python 3.8 windows:

**hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args, FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified**

Comment: HOST=<ip>
# Ports are handled in ~/.ssh/config since we use OpenSSH
COMMAND="uname -a"

ssh = subprocess.run(["ssh", HOST, "uname -a"],
                    shell=False,
                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                    check=False)

result = ssh.stdout.readlines()
if result == []:
    error = ssh.stderr.readlines()
    print >>sys.stderr, "ERROR: %s" % error
else:
    print (result)